# Command to open a file which contains the given data

Tags: linux

I had this question in interview.

He put a situation in front of me that there are 12 files in your Linux operating system.
Give me a command which will open a file containing data "Hello"..

I told him I just know `grep` command which will give you the names of files having "Hello" data.

Please tell me if there is any command to open a file in this way..

Comment: Define "open" --> edit with `vi`, print with `cat`... ?

Comment: `cat *` will open *all* the files, and will thus open the file that contains the data "Hello" in the process... My guess is, though, that isn't what they were looking for... Without more information, though, it's hard to say...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it will be only one file containing the word `hello`:

```
less $(grep -H "hello" *.txt | sed s/:.*//)
```

Here it is first capturing the file name using `grep` with `-H` parameter. Then using `sed` removing everything except the filename. And finally its using `less` to open the file.

Comment: Why not `grep -l hello *.txt`, and get rid of the `sed` bit?

Comment: @twalberg yeah, its even better. didn't know it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help:

```
$ echo "foo" > file1.txt
$ echo "bar" > file2.txt
$ grep -l foo * | xargs cat
foo
```

You have 2 files, and you are looking for the one with the string "foo" in it.  Change `cat` with your command of choice to *open* files.  Might try `vi`, `emacs`, `nano`, `pico`... (no, another flame war!)

You may want to try a different approach if there are several files that contains the string you are looking for...  Just thought of only **one** file containing the string.